# nginx with php 5.6 need to set up redirect for rest like calls

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I am using nginx version: nginx/1.10.3  with Zend Engine v2.6.0 for PHP.  This is running with in a docker container build on the following image:
**1and1internet/ubuntu-16-nginx-php-5.6**

I have a URL that I need to map in the configuration to be more "REST" like.  For example I want to map http://localhost/load.php?process=accounts
to something like this: http://localhost/load/accounts.  I

I know this is possible within the config files for nginix, but my nginx.conf file does not have a server block in it, and when I add the default one the container just dies.  I think there is something I'm doing in the server block that is causing it to fail.

Here is the server block code I am trying to add:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
```

As soon as I add this, nginx crashes.  I need to add the redirect into a server block.  I've looked over the other conf files and there are no other server blocks.

Is there another place I can add the redirect information?

I can't see the errors because the container crashes with this change.  It will only run for a few moments, so I don't have a chance to see the logs.

Comment: Nginx usually doesn’t crash because of a config entry, unless you managed to produce something like a Sefault (very unlikely). There should be a log file at `/var/log/nginx/error_log` or similar. If not, nginx might not be able to write that file, or your error reporting level is to high. Please try to find a relevant error message in the logs and post it.

Comment: You might also want to try to restart Nginx in foreground mode and look at the output, in case you’re 100% sure it crashes on startup.